# How To redirect Multiple Alternate URLs to a parent URL through HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I Have this Parent url for my website

```
 https://www.xyz.de
```

And there are alternate URLs too from where my site can be accessed like the followings:

```
Alternate URL 1: http://xyz.de/index.php
Alternate URL 2: https://www.xyz-zvb.de/index.php
Alternate URL 3: http://www.xyz-zvb.de/index.php
Alternate URL 4: http://xyz-zvb.de/index.php 
Alternate URL 5: www.xyz-zvb.de/index.php
```

But Now I want to redirect all these URLs to the main parent site URL every time User access the site with alternate website url it will redirect to the parent main URL.

I have tried like follows but in this case only one URL can be redirected and i think it is not a proffered way to do so.

```
Redirect 301 /contact.php http://example.com/contact-us.php
```

any help regarding this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.xyz.de/ [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: There are so many subtleties, it is difficult to see them all

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /index.php https://www.xyz.de
```

if xyz-zvb.de or www.xyz-zvb.de

```
# Permanent URL 
Redirect 301 / https://www.xyz.de
```

Comment: just try it, add it in htaccess file @Shoaib